# htaccessによる301リダイレクトの設定が動作していない

Tags: .htaccess

Googleでのページインデックスがおかしくなっていて、その解決のために301リダイレクトをしたい、という状況です。

具体的には、本来
(A)`http://example.com/bbb/1.html`
であるところ、
(B)`http://example.com/bbb//1.html`
とインデックスしているページが100ページ位あります。

`http://example.com/bbb/ccc/2.html`が、
`http://example.com/bbb//ccc/2.html`
となっているページもあります。

(B)にアクセスされたら(A)に飛ばしたく、
htaccessに以下を記述したのですがうまくいきません。

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^bbb//(.*)$ /bbb/$1 [R=301,L]
```

※上記htaccessは`http://example.com/`に置いてます。

適切な記述をご教示頂けましたら幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://teratail.com/questions/148648 が参考になると思います。
`RedirectMatch` を試してみてください。

Comment: Yanagiya様 ご回答ありがとうございました！
すぐに解決でき、大変助かりました。

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^bbb//(.*)$ /bbb/$1 [R=301,L]
```

これは

```
RewriteRule ^bbb//(.*)$ bbb/$1 [R=301,L]
```

これでも解決するのかなと思いました。